# Nativescript WebView capture onclick event

Tags: nativescript

I need to capture tap (click) events on a WebView (to display a picture in a SVG file), so that I can show another Nativescript page (or show another SVG) based on where the image is clicked..

Is there a way to capture a tap event with x,y coordinates for WebView?

Another thing. I found WebView can capture hyperlinks within the html loaded... Is there a way to make a link within the html so it open another local file within the nativescript app? For example: < a  href="~/stuff/foo2.html">here< /a >, but didn't work (where stuff is under my "app" folder) but I am getting a 404.

Comment: Not 100% on this, but don't think gestures will work on the webview. You can only work inside the webview and what it's running, so if you control the client site in that webview you could handle the click events in the website but the more I think about it I'm more confident that gestures cannot be executed on native apps inside the webviews. Because the webview is its own container that doesn't expose those events. I could be wrong but don't think I am :)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a possible solution.

Add some front end Javascript code to the page displaying in your WebView. Use that Javascript to detect taps on the page and when tapped redirect the WebView to a new (fake) page. On the NativeScript side, listen to the `loadStartedEvent` of the WebView (firing when the WebView navigates) and do something when the WebView tries to navigate to that new fake page.

I'd look something like this:

In the browser/WebView code. We add an event listener for `click` events (you probably want to change this to `tap` events). When clicked navigate the user to `nativescript://{X coordinate}/{Y coordinate}`.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    window.location.href='nativescript://' + event.screenX + '/' + event.screenY;
})
```

Then on the NativeScript side, set up an event listener listening for when the WebView is navigating and if it's navigating to a URL starting with 'nativescript://' then stop the loading event and extract the coordinates from the URL.

```
var wv = new webViewModule.WebView();
wv.on(webViewModule.WebView.loadStartedEvent, function(event) {

    // Check if the WebView is trying to navigate to 'nativescript://...'
    if (event.url.indexOf('nativescript://') === 0 ) {
        // Stop the loading event
        if (ios) {
            event.object.ios.stopLoading();
        } else if (android) {
            event.object.android.stopLoading();
        }

        // Do something depending on the coordinates in the URL
        var coords = event.url.split('/');
        coords.splice(0, 2);
        console.log(coords[0] + ' - ' + coords[1])
    }
});
```

As for loading local file, you just need to create a `file://` path to the local file. E.g.

```
var linkPath = fs.path.join(fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path, 'localHTMLFiles') + '/myFile.html';

var link = '<a href="file://" + linkPath + ">"'
```

Comment: Awesome! This approach may also help in any case when we need to get data from a web view.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `WebView` to `WebViewExt` https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@nota%2Fnativescript-webview-ext and grab links with

```
webview.on(WebViewExt.shouldOverrideUrlLoadingEvent, (_args: ShouldOverrideUrlLoadEventData) => {
   let blocked_url = _args.url;
 
   // Disable loading native app
   _args.cancel = true;            

   // Do some stuff and load another url..
});
```